# Calling properties/instance variables from strings in Objective-C

Tags: iphone

Basically my view controller has 49 different instance variables of class `CircleView` (called `circleView1`, `circleView2`, ..., `circleView49`). The `CircleView` class is a simple subclass of `UIImageView` and basically returns a circle picture when initialized.

Here is what I am trying to do:

In my implementation for the view controller, I want to be able to select the instance variable using a string, for example let's say I generate a random integer `i` between 1 and 49, lets say it's 5. I would like to be able to build an NSString using something like `[NSString stringWithFormat @"circleView%i",i];` and somehow reach the actual circleView5 instance variable. Is this possible?

P.S. I'm looking for something in the lines of `NSClassFromString`, but which applies to instance variables or objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KVC is your friend. Assuming you have a string with the name of the circleView in it,

```
NSString *myCircle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"circleView%i", i];
```

you access that property on the controller using KVC:

```
CircleView *theCircle = [self valueForKey:myCircle];
```

On a side note, you should consider redesigning the object heirarchary; this will be very difficult to maintain, and there are certainly better ways to do it (an array with the CircleView's accessed by index would be my first choice).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I had figured [self setValue: forKey:] already but this was what I needed!! thank you so much

Comment: Actually, it will work just fine with an ivar defined without a property or accessor methods.    And, yes, this smells like a re-architecture is in order.

Comment: @bbum Is that an intended use of KVC, accessing ivars directly? It seems like that would circumvent `willAccessValue`/`didAccessValue` plumbing.

Comment: I believe the willChange/didChange gunk is still fired.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a pile of variables and trying to access them via a string, use an array (either a primitive C array or an NSArray: I'll demo with an NSMutableArray). Declare a `NSMutableArray *circleViews;` in your class like you did the `circleViewN` instances. In your initializer, instead of a bunch of `circleViewN = [[CircleView alloc] init];`, you'd have something like:

```
circleViews = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];

for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
    [circleViews addObject:[[[CircleView alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

Then you can access the desired circle with your random int `i` with `[circleViews objectAtIndex:i];`.

Comment: This is a much better solution overall.

Comment: @CajunLuke: You're leaking memory here, You should be autoreleasing your `CircleView` objects when adding them to the array.

Comment: @Sedate True. I've been doing so much Java at work I forgot about that.